# Unable to pass textbox value from jsp to javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a textbox in one JSP page where the username is entered.Then i have another "Settings" page where there is link for "Change Password" where i have to do the validation username and password(password should not be same as username).But the lightbox for Change password contains only the oldpassword, newpassword and confirmpassword fields..I am wrting a samll function in JS to validate but the value of username is not reached till the js..How to do this??? Please help..

js

> 

```
function newcheckUsernamAndPassword(field, rules,i,options){        
> alert("i am  in new method");         var
> newpassword=field.val().toLowerCase();         alert("new pas"
> +newpassword);         var username='<%=Session("username")%>'        
> alert(username); //      var username =
> getValueUsingElementID('username').toLowerCase(); //     
> alert("Username"+username);         if(newpassword==username){        
> return options.allrules.changepassword.alertText;         }       }
```

code from Change password

```
<input type="password" style="width:150px" id="oldpassword" class=" > textBox validate[required,funcCall[checkOldpassword]" > onfocus="jQuery('#authenticateform').validationEngine('attach',{Overflown:false})"/></td> >         </tr> >         <tr> >             <td class="login"><label class="textLable"><msg:message > code="label.newpassword" /></label><span > class="redStar">*</span>&nbsp;</td> >             <td class="login"><input type="password" > style="width:150px" id="newpassword" name="newpassword" class="textBox > validate[required,maxSize[30],funcCall[checkOldAndNewPassword],funcCall[newcheckUsernamAndPassword],funcCall[validatePasswordCriteria]]" >              > onfocus="jQuery('#authenticateform').validationEngine('attach',{Overflown:false})"/></td> >         </tr>
```

Myadmin Page for Username

```
 <tr>   <td class="tblComponent" width="120px" ><label class="tblLabel" for="username"><msg:message code="label.components.userid"/><span class="redStar">*</span></label></td>   <td class="borderR tblComponent" width="120px" colspan="3"><input id="username" name="username" type="text" value="" onfocus="jQuery('#adduserform').validationEngine('attach',{Overflown:false})"/></td>    </tr>
```

Please help

Comment: Could you please improve on your formatting? It's rather illegible this way.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question. you can pass a textfield value to javascript by calling a javascript method function. Create a function and call it somewhat like on button. for e.g

```
<input type="button" onclick='abc();' value="Click"/>
```

now set an id on textfield. and call in javascript function somewhat like.

```
function abc(){
   var a = document.getElementById('textfieldID').val;
}
```

Sorry but your code is so messed up that i will look it again. but i think if you question is linked up to this(passing textfield from jsp to javascript) then try this.

Answer (score 0):

The best method to pass value of a text field to JavaScript is:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick='passValue(this);' value="Pass Value"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
function passValue(object){
   var value = object.value;
}
```